# Java mongodb driver and tomcat5.5 permission

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, debian, policy

I am using mongodb java driver r2.10.1
I used to test it with à java web application and tomcat5.5, with java 6 on Windows and Ubuntu.

Everything worked perfect until I test it out on Debian.
Here is a part of my stack trace error (removed stacktrace must remain private)

```
15:17:25 [TP-Processor10] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/epowerplant].[TechnicalVisitApi]  - "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet TechnicalVisitApi a généré une exception
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.checkAccess(LogManager.java:930)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.checkAccess(Logger.java:255)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setLevel(Logger.java:1131)
    at com.mongodb.Bytes.<clinit>(Bytes.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.<clinit>(DBTCPConnector.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:115)
    at com.common.business.bdd.MongoResource.getClient(MongoResource.java:79)
    at com.common.business.bdd.MongoResource.<init>(MongoResource.java:48)
    at com.common.business.bdd.MongoResource.getInstance(MongoResource.java:28)
    at com.commonTools.MongoConnector.getPool(MongoConnector.java:41)
    at ... (private)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.commonTools.web.filter.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I could make it work only if I edit the tomcat application policy

`vim /etc/tomcat5.5/policy.d/myapp.policy`

and add `permission java.security.AllPermission;`

then the application will work, but the system admin will refused to use this in production, how the hell can I find which permission needs mongodb to work  ? (I did google it)

Comment: Tomcat 5?  Oh, my.  Time to upgrade - we're up to Tomcat 8 now.  JDK would be my 2nd concern.  Production is 7.x and higher.  I'd look at security settings in MongoDB itself and maybe firewall rules from the server to the database.

Comment: We can't upgrade it, mongodb on debian is accessible from the webapp, it's really the web app that canno't connect to it, it's not about a firewall rules, (they are both in localhost), what about mongodb security settings ? can't find anything from the manual

Comment: I know that MySQL will ask you to GRANT permission to connect, access tables, and permissible operations by username and host. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/

Comment: I've already readen the link you gave me, it's just about database/user permission (not related to my problem). For mysql we need to do `permission java.util.PropertyPermission "javax.sql.*", "read"; 
`